# twilio list filter options

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio

I am using the example on the twilio API docs to get all messages available for an account and saving them locally, using the SID as a PK. I need to get only the new messages (greater than sendate timestamp?) I see on the page that there are options to filter the incoming messages, but I see no examples of how to "limit the list by providing certain query string parameters to the listing resource" as posted under "List Filters".

```
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
   static void Main(string[] args) 
   {
     // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
     string AccountSid = "AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
     string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
     var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var request = new MessageListRequest();

    var messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);

    foreach (var message in messages.Messages)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
    }
  }
}
```

Dont know if this is a separate question, but I also need to get only the last interaction I've had with each sentto number in my message list. I've scoured the twilio docs but may have missed something. If anyone can point me to the right resource I will bestow blessings on generations of their unborn progeny. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply using the options available on the [`MessageListRequest`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) class:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
   static void Main(string[] args) 
   {
     // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
     string AccountSid = "AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
     string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
     var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var request = new MessageListRequest();

    // 10 days ago.
    request.DateSent = (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(10));

    var messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);

    foreach (var message in messages.Messages)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what I needed. FYI - even knowing the name of the class, Google returns just 7 results, none very explicit, and twilio's help section returns 2,217 results, gonna take a long to to search all those. Thanx!

Comment: @Darkloki glad that was helpful. Please refer to [what should I do when somebody answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You may also want to revisit [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29836339/2573395) on one of your other recent questions.

Comment: This may be of interest to others looking for similar: twilio responded that currently their API supports filtering by DATE but not DATE RANGE.

Answer (score 2):

> to get greater than "send date" time stamp use
>   **MessageListRequest.DateSentComparison**

```
    using System;
    using Twilio;
    class Example 
    {
       static void Main(string[] args) 
       {
         // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
         string AccountSid = "AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
         string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
         var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        var request = new MessageListRequest();
        // 10 days ago.
        request.DateSent = (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(10));

        // this will do the comparison for greater than or equal to
        request.DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo;

       // use following if want to do less than or equal to
       //request.DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.LessThanOrEqualTo;

        var messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);

        foreach (var message in messages.Messages)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
        }
      }
    }
```